# Subscribe to PublishSubject in RxJava 2.0

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the following code which worked perfect in RxJava 1.6.

```
private PublishSubject<Boolean> mConnectionSubject;
...
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        mConnectionSubject.subscribe(subscriber);
        ...
    });
```

But after migration to RxJava 2.0 this code doesn't compile. The reason is that `Observable.create()` now accepts as argument `ObservableEmitter`. But PublishSubject doesn't accept `ObservableEmitter`. It accepts only `Consumer` or `Observer` interface.

Will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like below in the scenario you have mentioned.

```
Observable.<Boolean>create(emitter -> mConnectionSubject.subscribe(
    emitter::onNext,
    emitter::onError,
    emitter::onComplete
));
```

Comment: your suggestion is good, also I have some response to this issue on GitHub https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4787.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new observable, this should work:

```
private PublishSubject<Boolean> mConnectionSubject;
...
mConnectionSubject.doOnNext(...).observeOn(...).subscribe();
```

You can chain multiple operators/subscriptions to the PublishSubject.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, sorry. I wan't to know how can I use ObservableEmitter for future subscriptions. Because now int RxJava 2.0 it's different approach comparing to implementation how it was before.